# showing action sheet in the custom cell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I have a custom cell that contains a button inside it, I want to show an action sheet when the button is pressed, but as u know , UITableViewCell is doesn't have the method "presentViewController", so what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom cell's swift file, write a protocol to be conformed by your viewContoller,

```
// your custom cell's swift file

protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func showActionSheet()
}

class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    // This is the method you need to call when button is tapped.
    @IBAction func buttonTapped() {

        // When the button is pressed, buttonTapped method will send message to cell's delegate to call showActionSheet method.
        if let delegate = self.delegate {
            delegate.showActionSheet()
        }
    }
}

// Your tableViewController
// it should conform the protocol CustomCellDelegate

class MyTableViewController : UITableViewController, CustomCellDelegate {

    // other code

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // configure cell

        cell.delegate = self        

        return cell
    }

    // implement delegate method
    func showActionSheet() {

        // show action sheet

    }
}
```

Make sure your view controller conforms CustomCellDelegate protocol and implements showActionSheet() method.

Assign your viewContoller as delegate of the custom cell when creating your cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath dataSource method.

You can present your new view controller from the showActionSheet method in viewController.

Comment: Is there any tutorial explaining what you are talking about? I do know protocols , but I don't know about using it like that.

Comment: There may be some tutorials but instead I edited the answer. I hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do this:

1. Create a protocol on your customer `UITableViewCell` say `MyTableViewCellDelegate`.
2. Add a method `cellButtonTapped` in your protocol.
3. Conform your view controller (that uses these cells) to `MyTableViewCellDelegate` i.e. in the header file add `<MyTableViewCellDelegate>`.
4. In your view controller's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, when initializing cell, set self as delegate.
5. In your custom table view cell class, when button is tapped, handover the control to its delegate which is your view controller.
6. Implement method `cellButtonTapped` in your view controller and present action sheet as you like.