# How to call a ViewController from a UITableViewCell class

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a `UITableView` Class which controls the items in my custom cell. With one of these items I need to respond by moving to my `LoginView`. I set up a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with the selector called `priceClick()`. In this method I need to call `buildNewLoginView` but obviously can't use a segue so I call a class in my `MenuViewController` to show `LoginView`.

```
func priceClick() {
    MenuViewController.buildNewLoginView(MenuViewController)
}
```

This just throws an error

> 'Expression resolves to an used function'

What can I change so that I can call this method?

Comment: I had just explained as how to do this in [this thread][1]. Please take a look.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783933/showing-action-sheet-in-the-custom-cell-in-swift/32784864#32784864

Comment: Here you are calling the buildNewLoginView method on a class. You should create an object of it and call the buildNewLoginView method.

Comment: Thank you Abhinav that worked great and I learned something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both replies helped to fix my problem but the reply from Abinav was the solution I used and it worked perfectly by using a Protocol to declare the delegate which was assigned to my cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.